# Travelling to India from China - Limit on Customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, chinese-citizens

I am traveling to Kolkata, India, from Guangzhou, China for the first time, flying via China Eastern Airlines.

When discussing with friends how many items (electronics, jewellery, perfumes, watches, etc) we can take in checked luggage and/or carry-on bags there is always confusion. Some people say you can't take more than two phones or at most four electronic items. I was never worried about it until I found myself in this situation.

Can anybody provide an official link stating the amount of items I can take to India? Or any official resource where I can find the exact answer?

Comment: I swapped " ... India and China in your heading as it said From India to China ...". Hopefully that matches what you wanted. | I am not at all expert re imports to India but I have seen many questions which suggest that imports on more than a few such items is controlled. I'd guess that in any quantity you could at least expect to pay duty.

Comment: http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf

Comment: @DumbCoder My apologies for using the same link in the answer, I didn't see your link posted here earlier! :/

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for an official source, here's a [guide for travelers](http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf) freely available on the Central Board of Excise and Customs website for the Indian Government. They also happen to have a set of [baggage rules](http://www.cbec.gov.in/customs/cs-act/formatted-htmls/bgge-rules1998-ason11July2014.htm) complete with appendices which should clarify all the rules.

Regarding your specific questions and just for the sake of providing a short summary of the detail inside the document,

- Used personal effects (**excluding jewellery**) required for satisfying the daily necessities of life - Free
- Other articles carried in person or accompanied in baggage - Rs. 35000 if the stay is greater than 3 days
- One laptop computer (notebook computer) is allowed duty free if imported by any passenger of the age of 18 years and above
- Alcoholic liquors or wine up to 2 liters and Tobacco up to 200 cigarettes or 50 cigars etc.
- They are not very clear in the document regarding jewelry but as far as I understand, if you are carrying jewelry on your person and not in any sort of baggage (i.e. you are wearing it) you wont be liable to declare it, otherwise you will be.

Do read the document for an accurate insight into what is correct and valid.