# How many iPhones can I bring to India?

Tags: usa, india, cellphones, import-taxes

I have a confusion regarding the number of phones i can carry with me .
As the iphone is cheaper in usa compared to india i wish to carry many iphone's with me (what is the max limit) .

I also do not want to pay the import charges , let's suppose if i unpack the phone's and the earphone's from the box and carry it with me. will tell the officials that they are all mine will they allow me or not .

edit 1. - i dont plan to sell these phones , i'll give one to my wife and rest will be used by me as official phone , personal phone and backup phone

edit 2. - i know there are other question on this same topic but they dont answer what precisely i wanna know i.e. if i just keep all the phone without any packing and that too in seperate baggage (2 phones in 2 seperate luggage bags , 1 in my pocket and the last one in my hand bag ) will it still rightfully attract custom duty  .

Comment: Wouldn't that be fraud? In any case, we already have many questions on this, e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/how-many-iphone-6-devices-can-i-bring-into-india

Comment: There is nothing particularly confusing about the rules and they are certainly not designed to allow you to import stuff from cheaper countries. You're really asking about circumventing them.

Comment: According to the [previous question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/how-many-iphone-6-devices-can-i-bring-into-india), the rule is one phone, period. No matter how much you wish it weren't so and customs duties don't apply to you, I still don't see what's unclear about it. Removing the packaging, spreading phones between your bags or even giving some to fellow travelers might or might not work but it would be smuggling/circumventing the rules.

Comment: After all, you *are* actually trying to import phones (and a watch) and that's precisely the situation in which you're supposed to pay customs duties. Of course you'd rather not pay it but why would you assume there is a way to avoid it? What else would customs duty be for if people importing several brand new phones could do it duty-free?

Comment: The incredibly bizarre thing about all this is, I noticed phones **were cheaper in India!!!**.  I get the feeling it's **purely an out of date myth** that Mumbaikars, etc, think phone are "cheaper overseas".